# Google maps in modal only show gray color, after double click it display

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, bootstrap-modal

> Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var map;
   function initMap() {
     var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('gmap_basic');
     var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8
      }
     map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
     }
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
 </script>

 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='YOUR KEY'&callback=initMap"></script>
```

> CSS

```
#gmap_basic {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

> html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="gmap_basic"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Map</a>
```

> When running no error in console and network, but only gray color is showing in modal. After double click, maps is showing but only fullscreen option... (zoom option and satellite option is not showing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it occurs since `resize` event is never triggered, try to wrap it inside [.`ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to ensure `shown.bs.modal` event is triggered once DOM is loaded, like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        console.log('resize');
  });  
});
```

There is also another issue with how Google Maps is getting loaded.
Since the map is initialized via `callback` parameter, this line:

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

is not needed here.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/bL1rs03o/)

Comment: But I tried to take Co-ordinates to input boxes, after clicking maps it should show lat-long to Input textfields, again same problem is coming. (Map only gray) ;P